# Difficulty Installing Python Library "blpapi" Behind a Proxy

Tags: python, proxy, anaconda, bloomberg, blpapi

I'm currently facing issues while attempting to download and install a Python library called "blpapi." It seems that my company's proxy settings are causing obstacles. Here's what I've already tried:

Initially, I ran into problems downloading other libraries like "xbbg" and "blpapipd." Fortunately, these two libraries were available in our company repository, and the following configurations worked for them:

```
pip config set global.trusted-host repo-group.net
```

```
pip config set global.index-url https://repo1-group.net/repository/xbbg
```

```
pip install xbbg
```

As for "blpapi," I've attempted various methods, including proxy settings, but none have been successful:

1 :

```
pip config set global.trusted-host repo2-group.net
pip config set global.index-url https://repo2-group.net/repository/blplapi
pip install blpapi
```

2 :

```
python -m pip install --trusted-host rct-https://repo2-group.net --index-url=https://bcms.bloomberg.com/pip/simple --proxy="proxy:8000" blpapi
```

3:

```
python -m pip install --index-url=https://bcms.bloomberg.com/pip/simple blpapi
```

4 :

```
python -m pip install --index-url=https://repo2-group.net/repository blpapi
```

Now, I'm running out of ideas and need your help. Do you have any suggestions or recommendations to help me overcome this proxy-related issue? I'm open to considering any possible solutions you might have. Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Ish.

** I attempted several solutions I discovered online, but none of them were successful. It's possible that I might have implemented the solutions incorrectly. I also tried downloading the library manually, but I couldn't get it to work. I even attempted using different versions, but the issue persisted. Also, the proxy has a my user and a password **

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: As this seems to be a problem with your company's proxy, I'd suggest asking a coworker or your IT support for help. They will know much better the policies and procedures for your company

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I checked with them. It takes them a lot of time. So I was hopping I find a quick solution fr myself.

Comment: Just turn the proxy off in windows settings. Or set the proxy in your terminal.

set https_proxy=user:password@proxyIP:ProxyPort in your terminal. And it'll work. 

user: your computer login
pass: your computer password